# Process.Start runs on Windows 8 but crashes on Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, process

So I'm using the following code to perform a process using cmd.exe. It works fine on Windows 8 (my dev machine). However, when the executable is run from a Windows 7 computer, instead of getting the black pop up box with print out, its just a black box that flashes really fast and disappears with no error. There also seems to be nothing in the title of the cmd window except cmd.exe.

StandardOutput when the window closes, is blank.

wgetLocation is C:\Users\Kevin M\Desktop\wget\wget.exe

Also, when trying to catch the exception, there wasn't one.

Any help is appreciated.

```
        //Make Folder to Store files
        string downloadedFiles = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), txt_Site.Text);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadedFiles);

        //Get List of Sites
        //Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(wgetLocation);
        wgetLocation = Path.Combine(wgetLocation, "wget.exe");
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K " + wgetLocation + " --spider -r --adjust-extension -A html -A aspx " + txt_Site.Text;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();
        Console.Write(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        p.WaitForExit();
```

Working:
[image: working]
Not Working:
[image: not working]

Comment: Best guess: .NET can't find wget.exe on the Windows 7 PC. But without a better code example -- concise, complete, and reliable -- it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Change your code to log the exceptions, then it will be easy to find the issue.

Comment: Make sure that wget.exe is actually in `wgetLocation` on the Windows 7 machine.  Try using RedirectStandardError to write any error messages to a file.  Also check whereever you are directing RedirectStandardOutput.  Check the event log.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, what other information can I provide that would help?

Comment: are you hard coding the desktop location or are you using the [`SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration to get it.

Comment: No that is selected by the user using openFolderDialog

Comment: @Kyle: "what other information?" Well, like I said, a concise, complete, and reliable code example is what we'd really need. Your example relies on an environment that is too troublesome to reproduce (assuming it can be at all) for anyone else to both. But barring that, I suppose it would be helpful for you to retrieve and show the process exit code. If wget.exe is missing, I wouldn't expect an exception since the error happens in another process, not your .NET program, but the exit code would likely be some non-zero value.